# How to submit values for checked and unchecked dynamically named radio button groups with ColdFusion?

Tags: forms, button, coldfusion, radio-group

I have created a form for a user to upload various images into a gallery.  They can choose the image, which existing category (or create a new category) it should go into and whether or not to display the image as the "featured" image for that category.

Here is the form:

```
<FORM action='update_gallery.cfm' method='post' NAME="addform">
<TABLE align='center' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='5'>
<TR><TH>Delete</TH><TH>Image File</TH><TH>Preview</TH><TH>Category</TH><TH>New Category</TH><TH>Description</TH><TH>Featured?</TH></TR>
<CFOUTPUT QUERY="getGallery">
<TR>
<TD><INPUT NAME="ID" TYPE="checkbox" VALUE="#ID#" /></TD>
<TD>#IMAGE#</TD>
<TD><IMG SRC="../images/#IMAGE#" WIDTH='50' HEIGHT='50' /><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="IMAGE" VALUE="#IMAGE#" /></TD>
<TD>
    <SELECT NAME='CATEGORY'>
    <CFLOOP query="getCategory">
        <OPTION <cfif #getGallery.CATEGORY# IS '#getCategory.CATEGORY#'>SELECTED</cfif>>#getCategory.CATEGORY#</OPTION>
    </CFLOOP>
</SELECT>
</TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE='30' NAME='NewCATEGORY' VALUE="" /></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE='35' NAME="IMAGE_DESC" VALUE="#IMAGE_DESC#" /></TD>
<TD align="center">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="#CATEGORY#_PIC" ID="CATEGORY_PIC" VALUE="Yes" <cfif #CATEGORY_PIC# IS 'Yes'>CHECKED</cfif> />
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="CATEGORY_PIC" VALUE="#CATEGORY_PIC#">
</TD>
</TR>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="HiddenID" VALUE='#ID#' />
</CFOUTPUT>
<TR><TD COLSPAN='6' ALIGN='CENTER'>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="Submitted" VALUE='Y' /><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE='Process Updates' /></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
```

Here is the complicated part that I just can't figure out how to do -- for each unique category, there can only be ONE featured image selected, so I created a dynamically-named radio group for each category where only one item can be selected for each category.  When the form is submitted, the "unchecked" radio buttons do not exist as far as ColdFusion goes.  I need to submit a "No" value into the database for the unchecked buttons and a "Yes" value for the checked buttons.  This value should be the CATEGORY_PIC value, for which I've created a hidden form field.

I have been working on this for 4 days straight and searched every possible similar scenario I could find, but there is nothing identical to what I'm trying to accomplish.  It can't be that difficult, but I'm just not finding out how to do this.

I am running ColdFusion 9 with MS Access database.

Comment: It's a bit hard to determine where your problem is specifically.  Is it because you are not getting a "No" value passed? Remember your HIDDEN Category_PIC is probably incorrectly named ... should be
      <input type="hidden" name="#CATEGORY#_PIC"> ?  But more likely you need evaluate if there is a default for the category and only pass this if that's the case.

Comment: 1. Why are all your tags uppercase? 2. Access? Whatever you are trying to do will be doomed to fail until/unless you start using a real database.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you param them on your update_gallery.cfm page?

```
<cfparam name="CATEGORY_PIC" default="No">
```

for dynamic

```
<cfparam name="#category#_pic" default="no">
```

or

```
<cfscript>if(!isDefined('CATEGORY_PIC')){CATEGORY_PIC='No';}</cfscript>
<cfscript>if(!isDefined('#CATEGORY#_PIC')){'#CATEGORY#_PIC'='No';}</cfscript>
```

Comment: Without looking into the code more, cfparam seems like the likely answer. That or you can assume the lack of the variable is an indication it wasn't sent.

Answer (score -3):

```
<!--- Sample Data Set --->
<cfset gallery = "1,1.jpg,preview1.jpg,cat1,description1,true
5,5.jpg,preview5.jpg,cat1,description5,false
2,2.jpg,preview1.jpg,cat2,description2,false
6,6.jpg,preview6.jpg,cat2,description6,true
3,3.jpg,preview3.jpg,cat3,description3,false
7,7.jpg,preview7.jpg,cat3,description7,true
4,4.jpg,preview4.jpg,cat4,description4,true
8,8.jpg,preview8.jpg,cat4,description8,false">
<cfset category = "cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4">
<cfif isDefined('data')>
    <cfsetting showdebugoutput="false">
    <cfif isDefined(data)>
        <cfoutput>#evaluate(data)#</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
<cfelse>
    <!--- Populate Queries --->
    <cfhttp
        name="getGallery"
        method="get"
        url="#script_name#?data=gallery"
        firstrowasheaders = "no" 
        columns = "id,image,preview,category,image_desc,category_pic"
    />
    <cfhttp
        name="getCategory"
        method="get"
        url="#script_name#?data=category"
        firstrowasheaders = "no" 
        columns = "category"
    />

    <!--- Jennifer's Code --->   
    <form action='update_gallery.cfm' method='post' name="addform">
        <table align='center' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='5'>
            <tr><th>delete</th><th>image file</th><th>preview</th><th>category</th><th>new category</th><th>description</th><th>featured?</th></tr>
            <cfoutput query="getgallery">
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="id" type="checkbox" value="#id#" /></td>
                    <td>#image#</td>
                    <td><img src="../images/#image#" width='50' height='50' /><input type="hidden" name="image" value="#image#" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name='category'>
                            <cfloop query="getcategory">
                                <option <cfif getgallery.category eq getcategory.category>selected</cfif>>#getcategory.category#</option>
                            </cfloop>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" size='30' name='newcategory' value="" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size='35' name="image_desc" value="#image_desc#" /></td>
                    <td align="center">             
                        <input type="radio" name="#getGallery.category#_pic" id="category_pic" value="#id#" <cfif getGallery.category_pic>checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="hiddenid" value='#id#' />
            </cfoutput>
            <tr><td colspan='6' align='center'>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value='y' /><input type="submit" value='process updates' /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</cfif>
```

Comment: This is my best guess at what you're trying to accomplish. This difference here is that you are getting the new Featured Pic for the Category in the Form field... so you just write a query that sets all Features to NO, and set Feature to Yes for the one ID that is passed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using <cfhttp>?

Comment: OK..I think I figured it out. What an incredibly poor way to show populating queries. You are making 3 HTTP requests to the same page to load data (and dummy data at that). Why not just use queryNew()?

Comment: It is also a huge security hole considering you are running evaluate() blindly on data submitted by end users via the query string

Comment: I just did that to quickly simulate her query data. Was too lazy to use QueryNew and Inserts -- just used the built in HTTP CSV to Query feature, she wouldn't include the portion above the "Jennifer's" code portion. There would be no blind evaluates. Yeesh. ^_^

Comment: And I just realized that you can implcitly create queries in CF! ^_^ I thought you had to use QuerySetCell() for everything. Not sure when they added that.